# Setup makefile for 'path agnostic' inclusions

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

In my project files I just want to be able to say:

main.cpp:

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h>
```

When these headers files reside in separate

```
-Project
    -include
        -foo
           foo.h
        -bar
           bar.h
    -src
        main.cpp
```

I've setup my make file to attempt to achieve this but I still get `fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory` so I haven't been able to set it up correctly.

Makefile:

```
LIBS = ./include/foo ./include/bar

all:
    g++ -o bin/myapp src/main.cpp $(LIBS) -std=c++11
```

Is LIBS correct? How can I achieve relative/agnostic include paths?

Comment: you want the `-I` flag for setting directories for it to look for header files.  as in `g++ -o bin/myapp src/main.cpp -I./include/foo -I./include/bar -std=c++11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INCLUDES = -I./include/foo -I./include/bar

all:
    g++ -o bin/myapp src/main.cpp $(INCLUDES) -std=c++11
```